# `c('q01') %in% c('q01','q04')` should be TRUE,but doesn't work in condition loop

Tags: r

```
target<-data.frame(q01=1,q03=1:10)
total<-list(t1=c('q02','q05'),t2=c('q01','q04'),t3=c('q03','q06'))

for(m in colnames(target)){
  for(j in seq_along(total)) {
    if(m %in% total[j])
    print(names(total)[j])
  }
}
```

As `c('q01') %in% c('q01','q04')` is TRUE,the expect result of above script is:

```
t2
t3
```

But I cannot get any output,where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you could achieve this with

```
names(total)[sapply(total, function(x) any(x %in% colnames(target)))]

[1] "t2" "t3"
```

Comment: Advanced answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
target<-data.frame(q01=1,q03=1:10)
total<-list(t1=c('q02','q05'),t2=c('q01','q04'),t3=c('q03','q06'))

for(m in colnames(target)){
  for(j in seq_along(total)) {
    if(m %in% total[[j]])
      print(names(total)[j])
  }
}

[1] "t2"
[1] "t3"
```

Comment: Thanks!I didn't find this problem.

Comment: @kittygirl Great ! If you wish comfortable with this answer you could accept it :)